# Should an SSL certificate be made for www.domain.com or domain.com and how should it be configured?

Tags: ssl, server, certificate

When setting up a single domain website with an SSL certificate, what domain should the certificate be registered as for it to work properly with both www.domain.com and domain.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... to work properly with both www.domain.com and domain.com?

A certificate must match all domains which it should be used for. In this case it is enough to get a certificate containing these two domains. A certificate containing www.example.com only can not be used for example.com.

Comment: Thanks,  I guess the best way to do this is to make it so all SSL connections from domain.com get redirected to www.domain.com if I want to set it up that way...either that or get two separate certificates which doesn't seem practical.

Comment: @Thoughtful123: redirects of https connections need also a certificate for the dmain you redirect from. And is not untypical for a CA to offer cheap or free certificates which contain both example.com and a subdomain like www.example.com - for instance StartSSL offers this.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of SSL cert which do different things. My advice is to contact the Certificate issuer and ask them what you need.